# Is there any tool with which I can upgrade my CE database to 4.0?

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce-4

I'm having trouble creating a .NET project. I already have some database with extension ***.sdf*** and whenever I intend to connect to it I get the following error:

```
The database file has been created by an earlier version of SQL Server Compact. Please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrade() method.
```

Moreover I tried upgrading my database using the following snippets:

```
@using System.Data.SqlServerCe
@{
    var connStringCI = "Data Source= CRM.sdf;";
    SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStringCI);   
    engine.Upgrade(connStringCI);
}
```

This time I get the following compile error (Although I have included the .dll file in my project)

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeEngine' does not contain a definition for 'Upgrade' and no extension method 'Upgrade' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeEngine' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So I decided to use a third party tool that can do the upgrade for me. Can you introduce one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reference System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll version 4.0.0.0 in order to run Upgrade()

Comment: i've searched for it a lot, but no chance !

Comment: You may have to install it - it is normally in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop